# Finding files with same first few characters

Tags: windows, bash, shell

Im trying to find a windows shell command that will let me select all files starting with the same 3 characters. So for example if a directory had the following:

000hello
000world
111foo
121bar

the command would get me the first two files. Is there any way  to do this?

Comment: Windows shell or Bash? They're not the same. Since the techniques for doing what you want are vastly different, you should post two separate, properly tagged questions.

Comment: Please add cmd as tag/powershell as tag.

Answer (score 0):

use bash wildcards

```
$ echo 000*
```

Comment: "glob" is the term used in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Windows command line, right?

```
dir 000*
```

`*` is a wildcard character matching any characters in a filename

`?` is a wildcard character matching a single character in a filename

Based on your new info:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b 000*') do (
   echo %i is the name of the file we found
   type %i
)
```

If you're in a batch file, use `%%i`.

This assumes you want to stay in the current working directory.  If you want to walk the directory tree to sub-directories, look into using `for /r`.

Comment: He tagged his question with `bash` `shell` `script`, he must be using Cygwin. I'd agree it's confusing tho.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Yep.  I saw that too.  And I'm also confused.

Comment: the problem is that i want to select all files with 000, do some operation, then if other files with the same filenames such as 111 exist, do the same operation on them... and so on. so i dont know beforehand whats in the directory. I just select groups of files with the same prefix one by one and do some operation on them

Comment: Are you in Windows?  How does bash play into this?

Comment: thanks for the edit, but i do not know beforehand that files exist with the prefix 000. i just used that as an example. i want to search a dir and find ANY matching files with the same prefix, whatever that prefix may be. As for bash, i might also need to do it in linux in the future

Comment: @JohnBaum, eventually you're going to select every file in the directory, which is no different from `*.*`.  But I suspect you're doing something group-specific, which means the answer to your question (i.e., our target) will move once again even after we solve the grouping part.

Comment: i suppose i worded my question badly. Let me give it another try. I have a directory with some files. I want to select (one group at a time in a for loop or some such thing) all files that share a prefix. So if a folder has 6 files and 3 of them start with 001 and the other three with 002, i should get two groups back

Answer (score 0):

Since it is tagged Windows, it is not clear what types of solutions are desired, but if using Ruby is a possibility, this might work.

```
# create a hash of arrays where the hash value is the first three letters of the
# file name and the value is an array of those entries.
h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}
Dir.foreach(".") { |f| h[f[0..2]] << f }

# then print/use the ones that have multiple entries
h.each_key { |k| puts h[k] if h[k].length > 1 }
```